# How to devide a UIWebView into multiple pages (like iBooks)

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, ibooks

I am trying to build an application in which I need to divide the webpage into multiple pages. These pages will then be shown as the pages in a book, like the iBooks animation.

First problem to tackle is to divide the webpage into multiple pages and able to view it separately. Any inputs will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [this](http://highcaffeinecontent.com/samplecode/PageCurlDemo.zip) example code, although you must be forewarned that only Private APIs can be used to accomplish this task.

Comment: Seanny, Thanks for the link. But this is doing the page curl for a PDF. It is very easy to convert PDF into an image based page context. But the challenge I am facing is 'how to convert the webpage' into pages like this on iPhone/iPad. Also is there a way to make sure that the webpages will work as it (with the articles and links in them).

Comment: hey, did you find how to do that in the end?